# Javascript sessionstorage: unexpected value change

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, web, session-storage

I made a little "font-size widget" for my website. Now today I was looking to implement sessionstorage so users don't have to click the button all the time.

The standard font-size is 20. Now, I have no idea why, but sometimes, ONLY when I hit button2 (to have a bigger size) the value becomes literally 20 + 2 => 202. I don't know how or why.

*Does anyone have an idea on how to improve performance and solve this code? Or, if you think cookies are a better idea, how would I implement cookies for this piece of code?*

```
var currentSize;
function confSize(){
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize') == ""){
      $("#body").css("font-size", "20px");
  }
  else {
      currentSize = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize');
      $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");
      console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize'))
  }


    $("#button2").click(function(){
        if (currentSize == 20){
            currentSize = 22;
        }
        else {
            currentSize = currentSize + 2;
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionSize', currentSize);
        $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");
    });

    $("#button").click(function(){
        currentSize -= 2;
        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionSize', currentSize);
        $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you are correctly using values as strings and integers as appropriate.  If you do an operation like:

```
currentSize = currentSize + 2
```

You are going to get different values depending on whether `currentSize` is currently a string or an integer. If it is a string, you get the concatenation problem you note.

Now, you actually compound this with the problem that when you insert the integer `currentSize` value into `sessionStorage`, there is automatically a integer to string conversion made for storage (technically the `.toString()` method is called on whatever you are trying to store to determine the string value to be stored).  What you retrieve from `sessionStorage` will ALWAYS be a string value, such that you would need to cast it back into an integer before trying to do integer math on it.

I would suggest modifying your code to be explicit about strings/integers.  That might look like this:

```
var currentSize;
function confSize(){
   var defaultSize = 20;
   var sessionStorageStr = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize');
   if (sessionStorageStr == ""){
      currentSize = defaultSize;
   }
   else {
      currentSize = parseInt(sessionStorageStr);
      console.log(currentSize);
   }

   // no need to repeat this code in both sides of the conditional above
   $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");


   $("#button2").click(function(){
        // I removed your conditional here, as it really did nothing        
        currentSize += 2;
        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionSize', currentSize);
        $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");
    });

    $("#button").click(function(){
        currentSize -= 2;
        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionSize', currentSize);
        $("#body").css("font-size", currentSize + "px");
    });
}
```

Comment: By using parseInt(), I suppose? EDIT: when I use parseInt around the 2 sessionstorage.getItem (as shown above), the buttons don't work anymore... Do you have any idea what happens there?

So: `(parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize')) == "")` and 
`currentSize = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize'))`

Comment: @Kryptonous I added some sample code.  Can you elaborate on your statement that "buttons don't work anymore"?

Comment: I implemented your piece of code, which had the edits I also had, kind of. Now I hit the buttons, but nothing happens. Though it doesn't give any kind of error in console or elsewhere. Really strange... As if the default value won't change, but I don't think that's the issue... I don't know what the problem would be.

Comment: You never show in your OP how you initially call the `confSize()`. Is this happening? I am also assuming that `currentSize` is in global scope. Is that the case? Have you tried to debug further to see what happens when you are are clicking the buttons (i.e. are the click handlers firing? is the currentSize value what you expect? etc.)?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    confSize();
})`

Would that be the problem? I'll check if the handlers fire: EDIT: yes they do :)

Comment: OK and what happens when the handlers fire?  Can you do console.log the value for currentSize both before and after increment/decrement?

Comment: so I did a console.log(sessionstorage.getItem("sessionSize") which gave a `NaN`.console.log(currentSize) also gives a NaN.

Comment: I found the solution: I have to check if sessionstorage is not empty BUT also whether sessionstorage is not a number: so `if (sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize') == "" || isNaN(sessionStorage.getItem('sessionSize'))){
      currentSize = defaultSize;
   }`